# Kill command erroring out

Tags: shell, kill-process

We have a script that fetches all the active processes and kills it .
But for some reason i am getting the below error :

> :: INFO ::
>   /AA/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA\
>   Servers.sh :: 2016-06-26:04:00:04 : FORCE KILLING REMAINING SERVER
>   PROCESSES
>
> :: INFO ::
>   /AA/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA\
>   Servers.sh :: 2016-06-26:04:00:04 :force_stop_managed_servers
>   called**kill: usage\ : kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid |
>   jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspe\ c]**

My Script has the below function to force kill the processes.

```
function force_stop_managed_servers () {

        printf "\n\n:: INFO :: $0 :: `date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S` :force_stop_managed_servers called"
        cd $SCRIPT_DIR
        kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep SONARPOTY | grep $USER | grep -v "grep" | grep -v "StopManagedServers" | grep -v "controller"| awk '{ print $2 }')
        printf "\n\n:: INFO :: $0 :: `date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S` :force_stop_managed_servers done"
}
```

Please let me know why am i getting this error.

Comment: Try it with `set -x` and you'll probably see that `kill` gets called wrong. (Also, http://www.shellcheck.net will show you have some other potential errors.)

Comment: Ensure whether `$USER` is not empty and also the there is only one pid returned as result of the big command.

Comment: @Fazlin : The long command will NOT return a single process ID . It will return multiple processes. Can you please suggest what is the drawback if it returns multiple processes and also a possible solution to overcome that ?

Comment: I do not want to use a for loop, because the for loop will kill the processes one by one and it is possible that once i fetch the list and kill them one by one the process might have got completed and then the kill command will error out telling _No Such process_.

Comment: As far as i know, `kill` command does not work with multiple pid.s as argument. You might have to use loop.

Comment: @Fazlin : It does work with multiple PID's. As i mentioned above, _for_ loop is having the above drawback .. Moreover, The issue is intermittent. It doesn't comes always. one sometimes i see the issue and otherwise it works fine . So the uestion is which is that edge case where i am getting that issue.

Comment: Why not use `pkill -9 -u $USER 'pattern1|pattern2|pattern3'`?

Comment: @Fazlin - Here's the manpage of [kill(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill).

Answer (score 0):

This error is possible if 'kill -9' command called without argument. You can execute the long line command and assign the output to a variable. Later check that variable for not empty and pass that variable as argument to kill command.

Answer (score 0):

The `procps` package has better capability in handling process selection and sending signals to selected processes than `util-linux-ng` package combined with `grep`.

It is very common to see scripts that use `grep` to select a process id from the list of processes.

```
ps -ef | grep pattern | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

However, this can be shortened to:

```
pgrep pattern
```

Both cases will print the `PID` of the process whose name is `pattern`.
There is one caveat though, the second version only matches the pattern against process names.
If you need to match against command arguments you need something like:

```
pgrep -f pattern
```

Limiting the search for processes owned by user. Some attempts to `grep` username. Both `pgrep` and `ps` accepts `-u username` to list only the processes owned by user username.

Instead of writing:

```
ps -ef | grep username | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

Try:

```
pgrep -u username
```

If you need to kill these selected `PID`s, you won't need to run `kill` against the results. All you need is to use `pkill` instead of `pgrep`.

```
pkill -u username pattern
```

If you are truly limited to using `ps` and `kill` for whatever reason you may have, `ps` allows a formatted output. This way you can `grep` for pattern without inadvertently getting the `PID` of the `grep` itself.

```
kill -9 $(ps -u username -opid=.comm= | grep pattern | awk '{print $1}')
```

The only drawback with using `kill $()` is that `$()` may return empty and you'll get the error message you get. The solution is to toss the error message to `/dev/null`. `pkill` will not complain even when there is nothing to kill.

Finally, if you need to match against a command argument instead of the command itself, use `-opid=,args=` to output the arguments instead outputting the command.